# Make partitions based on difference in date in Postgres window function

Tags: postgresql-9.1, window-functions

I have data in the following format

```
    id  | first_name | last_name | birth_date
    abc | Jared      | Pollard   | 1970-01-01
    def | Jared      | Pollard   | 1972-02-02
    ghi | Jared      | Pollard   | 1980-01-01
    klm | Jared      | Pollard   | 2015-01-01
```

and I would like a query which groups data based on the following rule

**If first_name, last_name are equal and birth_dates are within 5 years of each other, than records belong to same group**

So the above data contains three groups group1=(abc, def), group2=(ghi) and group3=(klm)

Currently I have the following query which incorrectly creates only 2 groups, group1=(abc, def) and group2=(ghi, klm)

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    FIRST_VALUE(g.id) OVER (PARTITION BY lower(trim(g.last_name)), lower(trim(g.first_name)), 
    CASE WHEN g.birth_date between g.fv_birth_date - interval '5 year' AND g.fv_birth_date + interval '5 year' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ORDER BY g.last_used_dt DESC NULLS LAST) AS cluster_id
FROM (
      SELECT id, last_used_dt, last_name, first_name, birth_date,        
      FIRST_VALUE(birth_date)
           OVER (PARTITION BY
           lower(trim(last_name)),
           lower(trim(first_name))
           ORDER BY last_used_dt DESC NULLS LAST) AS fv_birth_date
      FROM guest
) g;
```

I understand this is because of the CASE statement within the PARTITION BY clause but am unable to come up with any other query

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.